# XSLT apply templates to tree part

Tags: xslt

I have the XML tree:

```
<text>
    <plain>abcd<c>efgh</c>ijklm</plain>
    <plain>nopq<c>rst</c>uvw<c>xyz</c></plain>
    <rp><first><c>asdasd</c>asf</first><second>asdasd</second></rp>
    <plain>aaaaa<c>bbbb</c>ccccc<c>xyz</c></plain>
</text>
```

Then I have code in my XSLT stylesheet ($product_text contains above tree):

```
<xsl:template name="text_list">
<xsl:if test="$text_count &gt; 0">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="text_item" select="$product_text/text">
        <xsl:sort select="@rating" order="descending" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="text_item" match="*">
    <div class="cmp-post">
        <xsl:copy-of select="./*" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

This fragment copies all tree as-is. But I need all "c" nodes to be replaced/modified like this:

```
<c>efgh</c>
to
<cmp attr="efgh">efgh</c>

<c>rst</c>
to
<cmp attr="rst">rst</c>
etc
```

(edited) Result I expect:

```
<div class="cmp-post">
    <plain>abcd<c attr="efgh">efgh</c>ijklm</plain>
    <plain>nopq<c attr="rst">rst</c>uvw<c attr="xyz">xyz</c></plain>
    <rp><first><c attr="asdasd">asdasd</c>asf</first><second>asdasd</second></rp>
    <plain>aaaaa<c attr="bbbb">bbbb</c>ccccc<c attr="xyz">xyz</c></plain>
</div>
```

How should I modify text_item template?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't jive with your template.  Aren't you saying that you want to wrap the matched element in a `<div class='cmp-post'/>` element?

Comment: Yes, result should be wraped in div. But it is easy and it works, so I missed this part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to do `apply-templates` instead of `copy-of`.  `copy-of` just copies the node; it doesn't do template matching and invocation on the copied elements.

As such, you'll need a few additional templates to get what you want.

```
<!-- Copy attributes as-is -->
<xsl:template match="@*" mode="text_item">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- By default, copy element and text as-is then apply matching on children -->
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="text_item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="text_item"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- For 'text' elements, use div instead of direct copy -->
<xsl:template match="text" mode="text_item">
    <div class="cmp-post">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="text_item" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c" mode="text_item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name='attr'><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="text_item" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note that the `@*` template is just for completeness.  Your current input doesn't have any attributes, but if it did, this would copy them to the output.)

Running the above templates on your input with this as a caller

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="text_item">
  <xsl:sort select="@rating" order="descending" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

gives the output

```
<div class="cmp-post">
    <plain>abcd<c attr="efgh">efgh</c>ijklm</plain>
    <plain>nopq<c attr="rst">rst</c>uvw<c attr="xyz">xyz</c></plain>
    <rp><first><c attr="asdasd">asdasd</c>asf</first><second>asdasd</second></rp>
    <plain>aaaaa<c attr="bbbb">bbbb</c>ccccc<c attr="xyz">xyz</c></plain>
</div>
```

It should be the same when called against a node variable.